# C# Calculator , how to point an Input to the answer?

Tags: c#, .net, calculator

I am making a calculator on C#.
I have to use float because, when I divide numbers, I get an answer less than 0.
but, I want the calculator to begin the new calculation with the answer i already got, So i wrote:

```
 a = Convert.ToInt64(answer);
```

but, it doesn't help, it converts the answer to int64 too. 
I think, I will be able to do with pointers, but I don't know how.

So how can I copy the value of answer to 'a' (the Input), without converting answer?

```
    Int64 a; //1st Input
    Int64 b; //2nd Input
    float answer;
    char d;
    bool pressed;
   private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (d == '+') answer = a + b;
        if (d == '-') answer = a - b;
        if (d == '*') answer = a * b;
        if (d == '/') answer = a / b;
        textBox1.Text = a.ToString() + d + b.ToString() + '=' +answer.ToString();
        a = Convert.ToInt64(answer);
        b = 0;
    }
```

sorry, for the lack of the whole source code, if anybody want's me to add them too just tell me :)

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any pointers in the code you posted, so I'm removing the tag.

Comment: You cannot learn C# by asking questions and reading answers. Go find yourself a book and learn C#. Then, when you come across some real problem, come back here for help.

Comment: An Int64 (also known as long) can hold values less than zero. A float is only used if you need to preserve fractional values. Either convert a and b to a more precise data type, or you will have to round the answer by casting. I would recommend making a and b decimal types.

Comment: Should `a` be defined as a `float` and not as an `Int64`?

Comment: You don't need pointers. You could try using `Convert.ToSingle()`. There's a whole lot more going on here that could probably be separate questions...

Comment: It converts the answer to an `Int64` because that is exactly what you are telling it to do. `a` needs to be stored as a `float`. Also, C# doesn't have pointers, not really. Certainly not like C or C++.

Comment: Why are you using int64? The division of two Int64 numbers should be a number that has ability to have a decmial value. This has nothing to do with pointers. Your code is just wrong. What do you get when you devide 1 by 2? Jeff - Your statement about C# not having pointers while semi-accurate doesn't tell the entire story.

Comment: @Jeff Unsafe C# most certainly can use pointers. Not that there's really *ever* a reason to do so.

Comment: No this is not a Homework. i am making a calculator because i am studying C# now and want to improve my knowledge with a small experience, and get used to C# syntax. i tagged pointers because i think the answer is about pointers, should i not tag like this?

Comment: @vato - When your not using pointers, your problem has nothing to do with pointers, then you should avoid the tag.

Comment: If you want to learn c#, Please forget all you know about pointers. You won't need them.

Comment: when i divide 1 by 2 i get 0, but when i divide 1 by 2 and a is float, i get 0.5.

Comment: @CMP - Funny.  I can think of many reasons to use pointers even when using C#.

Comment: @Vato - In both cases the answer is correct.

Comment: @Rahmhound You are of course correct and I was purposefully simplifying. Someone learning C# will be better off forgetting about pointers until they run into the advanced situations like interoperability and performance micromanagement that require them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of observations that may help:

1. Your inputs probably shouldn't be Int64 in the first place, as it is unlikely the user will work only in whole numbers, especially once they start using division.
2. Your answer and your inputs should be the same type, this will remove your casting issues.
3. Float is imprecise and may not be the best option.  If you need better accuracy than Float can allow, you may try Decimal.  (if you are unaware of the limitations of floating point arithmetic, Google for it)

Comment: i want to make the calculator give not whole answer, how can Decimal help me?

Comment: Ints of all sizes are for integer (whole) numbers only.  Decimal is a precise type that allows for non-whole numbers.  If you move everything to decimal, you can remove your Convert.ToInt64() call as well.

Answer (score 1):

First off guys, he's not asking how to make a calculator, he's just asking for help on a specific problem, I think that's what SO is supposed to be about.

You are on the right track, just needs some adjustments.

**Operations**

You most likely don't need `Int64`, you are probably looking for `float` or `double`. So here is a simple example:

```
float a = 1.0f; 
float b = 2.0f; 
float answer = a / b;
```

Here the answer would be `0.5`, if `a` and `b` were integers the answer would be 0. If either one (or both) are `float` or `double` then the answer will be a decimal number.

**If Statement**

While we are at it, your if statement can be improved by making it an if-else:

```
if (d == '+') answer = a + b;
else if (d == '-') answer = a - b;
else if (d == '*') answer = a * b;
else if (d == '/') answer = a / b;
```

Why? Because `d` is only going to be *one* of those strings (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`). With if-else, once a case is true the rest of the if's are skipped. With your code, even if d is +, the other three if statements are still checked.

Comment: thanks but, are there any possibilities to leave a and b int64, get the answer in float and at last make 'a' equal to answer, to continue calculation? because, i want to let the user type more than 10 digits input.

Comment: In that case you can use double instead of float. Double is a 64-bit number while float is a 32-bit number.

Answer (score 0):

Two options to consider:

- Do only integer division.
- Use floating point variable types for both input and output.